# Mathematics of Handcuff Puzzle

Tags: puzzle, geometric-topology

[image]

Iwant to learn mathematics of Handcuff Puzzle in the clearest way. What is the basis of it? topology or geometry? I couldn’t find sufficient infos on the google.

I think it is about homeomorphism thus topologic equivalences. I wonder the reason. Which homeomorphism between which surfaces or knots or etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Topology more than geometry

Comment: @Henry I think it is about homeomorphisms but I want to see which homeomorphism and between which knots or rings